# How to use multiple whereEqualTo condition on the same query on different fields

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat application. I am uploading the messages to firestore with fields docId(document id), textMessage(actual message), fromId(id of the user who sent the message), toId(id of user to whome the message is sent), createdAt(time at which the message is sent). I want to fetch the message to show in the chatLog activity. I am fetching the messages using the following query

```
val reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("messages")
            .whereEqualTo("fromId", currentUser.userId)
            .whereEqualTo("toId", otherUser.userId)
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)


reference.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if(error != null){
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            if (value != null) {
                for(dc in value.documentChanges){
                    if(dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        val message = Message(
                            dc.document["id"].toString(),
                            dc.document["textMessage"].toString(),
                            dc.document["fromId"].toString(),
                            dc.document["toId"].toString(),
                            dc.document["createdAt"].toString()
                        )

                        Log.d(TAG, "listenForMessageChange: ${dc.document["textMessage"]}")

                        messageList.add(message)
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageList.size-1)
                        etMessage.text.clear()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I think the query is not working properly and is returning all the messages which have fromId and is not checking for the toId field.

Please tell me is there a way to get all the messages which have both fromId and toId fields.

otherUser.userId is NnbqRLY0haTYgtat3LYZQAEl1oP2 and currentUser.userId is lrFpBpZJQXdieUwSMnXAop4vugt1

"I am good. What about you" is showing in the current signed in account. And in other account, "hi" is showing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The query looks fine at first glance. If you're getting unexpected results, please edit your question to show the code that reads the data and logs the unexpected values (i.e. the `fromId` and `toId`).

Comment: Thanks. Please in your code log the unexpected output values, and share that updated code and its output. That way, we're all looking at the same thing.

Comment: Add `println(dc)` just before the `var message = ` line and confirm that it is printing to the console the documents you are querying for If it queried successfully you will be able to see the document printed in the console means there is something wrong with Message class or with messageList.